# Can I have thread_local object which ctor/dtor will be called on each thread creation even if it is not used?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm still new to C++11 thread_local storage. In particular I'm curious about following code:

```
class foo_t
{
    foo_t() { std::cout << "Foo ctor"; }
    ~foo_t() { std::cout << "Foo dtor"; }
}

thread_local foo_t foo;

void bar() {  }
void baz() {  }
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(bar), t2(baz);
    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

Will the ctor/dtor of `foo_t` be called twice in this example (I mean does the standard requires so)? What if I move `bar` to other translation unit? What if such unit won't have a declaration of `foo_t` nor `foo`?

Comment: Have you tried it?  What happened?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't want to trick myself that it works, when it may not on different compiler / OS / whatever

Comment: [Surprise!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbdd839c237ad17b) It's not even called once.

Comment: @Zereges Uh, that's why I did not want myself to trick that it works everywhere :-(

Comment: It's still a good idea to see what it does on your actual machine.  At least we could use that as a starting point for discussion...or as in the case here, it might make you ask an entirely different question.  It's not 1960 anymore, compiling is free!

Comment: I don't understand not trying things to see how they work. Be curious!! Try things!! Break things and then fix them. You see how it behaves on your machine and then you ask if it is required, implementation default, allowed optimization or undefined behavior, or whatever. But there is absolutely no point  in not trying yourself, except maybe laziness.

Comment: @bolov Yup, but accidentally this code works as I desired to do so on my MSVC...

Comment: It does not work on clang / gcc through. I am not a fan of "I typed it and it works, so it must work everywhere!" kind of stuff... You know, C++ has plenty of UBs and compilers extensions...

Comment: The standard says: "**[basic.stc.thread]/2** A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use (6.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on thread exit." I read it as the variable doesn't have to be initialized if it is never odr-used.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you post this as answer, with info about what is odr-use?