# How to mark each thread with named token as automatically as possible in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have requirement to account all threads in C++/17' application we're going to develop;

The thread accounter iteself is `thread_local` object that keeps information regarding the thread and is able to report it back to main module.

The problem is `thread_local` objects needs to be called from each thread at least once, to be even constructed (see: [Can I have thread_local object which ctor/dtor will be called on each thread creation even if it is not used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352907/can-i-have-thread-local-object-which-ctor-dtor-will-be-called-on-each-thread-cre)). After that it will be properly destructed on thread exit.

My initial thought is to make such construction:

```
thread_local thread_accounter_t thread_accounter; // This is main accounter object

void thread_started(std::string name, std::string function, std::string filename, int line)
{
   thread_accounter.thread_started(name, function, filename, line);
}
#define THREAD_STARTED(name) thread_started(name, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Then, in each thread use:

```
std::thread my_thread([](){
    THREAD_STARTED("example");
    // Do actual job
});
```

That way has a very strong drawback: it is prone to error. Every thread that don't use the macro (ie. due to overlook) will be invisible to accounter.

My next idea would be to inherit `std::thread` and override it's constructor. This way, when someone uses `our::thread` they will be forced (by constructor) to populate thread name. By using simple tricks we can force user to not use `std::thread`.

```
class thread : public std::thread
{
   public:
       thread_t() noexcept {}
       thread_t( thread_t&& other ) noexcept : std::thread(std::move(other)) {}
       template<class function_t, class... args_t >

// Following constructor actually does not compile:
       explicit thread_t(std::string name, std::string function, std::string filename, int line, function_t&& f, args_t&&... args ) :
       std::thread(std::bind([name, function, filename, line](function_t&& f, auto&&... args){
           thread_started(name, function, filename, line);
           f(std::forward(args)...);
       }, std::move(f), std::move(args)...)) { }
       thread_t(const thread_t&) = delete;
};
#define THREAD_NAME(name) name, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__
```

Then just use it:

```
thread my_thread(THREAD_NAME("sample thread"), [](){
    // Do actual job
});
```

The questions are two fold:

1.) If my approach is good, how can I fix the constructor of `thread` so it will compile?
Minimal sample: https://pastebin.com/mNMpunMT

2.) If my approach can be corrected, what is the better way to do it?

Comment: `thread_t( thread_t&& other ) noexcept : std::thread(static_cast<std::thread&&>(std::move(other))) {}`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks! It is still not compiling through....

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Add code for using it - then the templates will be build and still fail

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki See: https://rextester.com/live/NEZNA91749

Comment: A drawback I see from your approach is that you will inevitably end up looking up your application's threads at the OS level to monitor threads that could be spun up by libraries (including the standard library). So you might as well use OS-level features (like `pthread_setname_np()`) from the get-go.

Comment: @Frank I am aware, we are required to account at least all of our own threads. The OS monitor will be added later on, if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it!

The `std::bind` is not required, since `std::thread` constructor can accept arbitrary arguments. So, here is the final version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void thread_started(std::string name, std::string function, std::string filename, int line)
{

}

class thread_t : public std::thread
{
   public:
       thread_t() noexcept {}
       thread_t( thread_t&& other ) noexcept : std::thread(static_cast<std::thread&&>(std::move(other))) {}
       template<class function_t, class... args_t >

       explicit thread_t(std::string name, std::string function, std::string filename, int line, function_t&& f, args_t&&... args ) :
       std::thread([name, function, filename, line](function_t&& f, auto&&... args){
           thread_started(name, function, filename, line);
           f(std::move(args)...);
       }, std::move(f), std::move(args)...) { }
       thread_t(const thread_t&) = delete;
};
#define THREAD_NAME(name) name, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__

int main()
{
    thread_t my_thread(THREAD_NAME("sample thread"), [](){
        // Do actual job
       std::cout << "Hello!";
    });
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```